# Extend automatically Panel with Tabs in Powershell

Tags: tabs, extend, autosize

I have a frame which contains one panel with Tabs. When I extend the main frame, I vould like my panel was extended too. Can you tell me what can I do for, please ?

function Show-tabcontrol_psf {

```
#----------------------------------------------
#region Import the Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
#endregion Import Assemblies

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Objects
#----------------------------------------------
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$tabcontrol1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl'
$tabpage1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
$tabpage2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------

$form1_Load={

}

# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Events
#----------------------------------------------

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    #Remove all event handlers from the controls
    try
    {
        $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
        $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch { Out-Null  }
}
#endregion Generated Events

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
#----------------------------------------------
$form1.SuspendLayout()
$tabcontrol1.SuspendLayout()
#
# form1
#
$form1.Controls.Add($tabcontrol1)
$form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
$form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$form1.ClientSize = '453, 517'
$form1.Name = 'form1'
$form1.Text = 'Form'
$form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
#
# tabcontrol1
#
$tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage1)
$tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage2)
$tabcontrol1.Alignment = 'top'
$tabcontrol1.Location = '12, 12'
$tabcontrol1.Multiline = $True
$tabcontrol1.Name = 'tabcontrol1'
$tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 0
$tabcontrol1.Size = '429, 478'
$tabcontrol1.TabIndex = 0
#
# tabpage1
#
$tabpage1.Location = '42, 4'
$tabpage1.Name = 'tabpage1'
$tabpage1.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
$tabpage1.Size = '583, 442'
$tabpage1.TabIndex = 0
$tabpage1.Text = 'tabpage1'
$tabpage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# tabpage2
#
$tabpage2.Location = '23, 4'
$tabpage2.Name = 'tabpage2'
$tabpage2.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
$tabpage2.Size = '602, 442'
$tabpage2.TabIndex = 1
$tabpage2.Text = 'tabpage2'
$tabpage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#


#----------------------------------------------

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
return $form1.ShowDialog()
```

} #End Function

## Call the form

Show-tabcontrol_psf | Out-Null

## ----------------------------------------------

function Show-tabcontrol_psf {

```
#----------------------------------------------
#region Import the Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
#endregion Import Assemblies

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Objects
#----------------------------------------------
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$tabcontrol1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl'
$tabpage1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
$tabpage2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------

$form1_Load={

}

# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Events
#----------------------------------------------

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    #Remove all event handlers from the controls
    try
    {
        $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
        $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch { Out-Null  }
}
#endregion Generated Events

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
#----------------------------------------------
$form1.SuspendLayout()
$tabcontrol1.SuspendLayout()
#
# form1
#
$form1.Controls.Add($tabcontrol1)
$form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
$form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$form1.ClientSize = '453, 517'
$form1.Name = 'form1'
$form1.Text = 'Form'
$form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
#
# tabcontrol1
#
$tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage1)
$tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage2)
$tabcontrol1.Alignment = 'top'
$tabcontrol1.Location = '12, 12'
$tabcontrol1.Multiline = $True
$tabcontrol1.Name = 'tabcontrol1'
$tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 0
$tabcontrol1.Size = '429, 478'
$tabcontrol1.TabIndex = 0
#
# tabpage1
#
$tabpage1.Location = '42, 4'
$tabpage1.Name = 'tabpage1'
$tabpage1.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
$tabpage1.Size = '583, 442'
$tabpage1.TabIndex = 0
$tabpage1.Text = 'tabpage1'
$tabpage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# tabpage2
#
$tabpage2.Location = '23, 4'
$tabpage2.Name = 'tabpage2'
$tabpage2.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
$tabpage2.Size = '602, 442'
$tabpage2.TabIndex = 1
$tabpage2.Text = 'tabpage2'
$tabpage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#


#----------------------------------------------

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
return $form1.ShowDialog()
```

} #End Function

## Call the form

Show-tabcontrol_psf | Out-Null

Answer (score 0):

I have an incomplete solution

```
$TabControl.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom

$TabControl.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right
```

I have to gather this two lines and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the solution :

```
$TabControl.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top 
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom 
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left 
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right
```